# Properly capture chapter name

Tags: sectioning, koma-script

I have a code that looks like the following:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[automark]{scrpage2}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\let\oldchapter\chapter
\newcommand\temphead{}
\newcommand\chaphead{}
\renewcommand\chapter[2][\temphead]{%
    \renewcommand\temphead{#2}%
    \renewcommand\chaphead{#2}%                     
    \oldchapter[#1]{#2}}

\title{My title}

\makeatletter             
\let\titlehead\@title         
\makeatother

\cfoot[\rule{6mm}{0.8pt}\\\pagemark]{\rule{6mm}{0.8pt}\\\pagemark}
\ofoot[]{}
\lehead[]{}
\cehead[]{\titlehead}    
\cohead[]{\chaphead}                                          
\ohead[]{}

\renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{scrplain}


\begin{document}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\chapter{My first chapter}

\lipsum
\lipsum


\chapter{My second chapter}

\end{document}
```

The goal is to display the chapter name on right pages, and the title of the book of left pages.

Now when the page preceding a new chapter is a right page, the chapter displayed is the one of the following chapter. My sample code shows it, as the last page of the first chapter says "My second chapter".

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `\clearpage` or (`\cleardoublepage` if needed) right before `\chapter{My second chapter}`.

Comment: For some reason, my full code has a `\cleardoublepage` but it doesn't fix the issue. I'll try to update the example to reproduce my error.

Comment: It seems my issue was that I used `\input` instead of `\include` in my main document to include chapters. Any idea why that would produce this effect?

Comment: `\include` contains a `\clearpage` command in its definition; `\input` does not add `\clearpage`.

Comment: I think, the main problem isn't using `\clearpage` or `\cleardoublepage` or `\input` or `\include` but not using the mark mechanism of TeX (see esdd's answer).

Answer (score 1):

The normal `\chapter` contains a `\cleardoublepage` (which acts like `\clearpage` in one-sided documents). You need to add a `\cleardoublepage` before changing the header to flush out the last page of the previous chapter. The second `\cleardoublepage` in the `\oldchapter` will no cause any empty pages.

```
\renewcommand\chapter[2][\temphead]{%
    \cleardoublepage
    \renewcommand\temphead{#2}%
    \renewcommand\chaphead{#2}%
    \oldchapter[#1]{#2}}
```

This makes your new `\chapter` work with `\input` and `\include` or in the main file.

Comment: I think, the main problem isn't using `\clearpage` or `\cleardoublepage` or `\input` or `\include` but not using the mark mechanism of TeX (see esdd's answer).

Answer (score 1):

Do *not* redefine the `\chapter` command to change the header entry for chapters. To remove the chapter number from the header marks simple redefine `\chaptermarkformat` to do nothing:

```
\renewcommand\chaptermarkformat{}
```

Note that `scrplain` is used as `\chapterpagestyle` by default when `scrlayer-scrpage` (or `scrpage2`) is loaded and pagestyle `scrheadings` is set for the normal pages.

Example with package `scrlayer-scrpage` (successor of `scrpage2`):

```
\documentclass
[footheight=27.2pt]% as suggested by scrlayer-scrpage
{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}% only for dummy text

\renewcommand\chaptermarkformat{}% remove the chapter number from header entries

\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}% sets pagestyle scrheadings
\clearpairofpagestyles
\cfoot[\rule{6mm}{0.8pt}\\\pagemark]{\rule{6mm}{0.8pt}\\\pagemark}
\cehead{\titleheading}
\cohead{\leftmark}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\titleheading{\@title}
\makeatother
\title{My title}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\chapter{My first chapter}
\lipsum[1-15]

\chapter{My second chapter}
\lipsum[1-200]
\end{document}
```

---

Example with the outdated package `scrpage2`:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}% only for dummy text

\renewcommand\chaptermarkformat{}% remove the chapter number from header entries

\usepackage[automark]{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearscrheadfoot
\cfoot[\rule{6mm}{0.8pt}\\\pagemark]{\rule{6mm}{0.8pt}\\\pagemark}
\cehead{\titleheading}
\cohead{\leftmark}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\titleheading{\@title}
\makeatother
\title{My title}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\chapter{My first chapter}
\lipsum[1-15]

\chapter{My second chapter}
\lipsum[1-200]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I used `\input` instead of `\include` to include chapter files. This caused the `\chaphead` macro to contain the wrong value. Any explanation as to why this would happen is welcome.

Comment: `\include` contains a `\clearpage` or `\clearand so flushes the last page of the previous chapter. `\input` does not include one. Simply add a `\cleardoublepage` in the front of your macro as shown in my answer and you don't have to worry about how you include the `\chapter`.

Comment: I think, the main problem isn't using `\input` or `\include` but not using the mark mechanism of TeX (see esdd's answer).